# why is this code generating three array values instead of one? python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class, called `general`, with an array `msgs[]` as an attribute. There is also an attribute called `msg`, which is a string. I instantiate three classes, `gen0, gen1, gen2` and store each object in an array called `arr (arr = [gen0, gen1, gen2])`.

I have defined a method on class `general` called `snd(self, id, somemsg)` which, given the id (to point to the object at the index `id` in the array `arr`), appends a string `somemsg` to the array `msgs[]`.
For example, `gen0.snd(1,"hello")` will perform `gen1.msgs.append("hello")`.

```
def snd(self, dst, msg):
    listGens[dst].msgs.append(msg)
```

I have defined the following function, where `general` is an instantiation of class as defined above.

```
def playGeneral(general):
    for val in listGens:
        if(val.id is general.id):
            general.snd(general.id, " ")
            continue
        general.snd(val.id, general.oc)
```

When calling`playGeneral(gen0)`, the `somemsg` variable has been set to `genX.msg = "A"`, i.e. the `gen0.msg`, which happens to be "A"; doing this, we get

```
playGeneral(listGens[0])
    for val in listGens:
    print(val.msgs)

[' ', 'A', 'A']
[' ', 'A', 'A']
[' ', 'A', 'A']
```

I can't understand why this is happening. It should be yielding

```
[' ']
['A']
['A']
```

Comment: Wouldn't the answer depend, at least in part, on the code for `general.snd`, which you have failed to provide?

Comment: i explained, verbatim, what it does, but i have included the code.

Comment: Also relevant code would be to show how the `msgs` attribute on `general` is initialised.

Comment: @socrates: did you notice how your "verbatim explanation" wasn't very useful, and the answer was instead found by guessing common errors that beginners often make?  This is why we prefer a [mcve] to a description, however confident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psychic debugging: Your `general` class is defined like this:

```
class general:
    msgs = []
```

or:

```
class general:
    def __init__(self, msgs=[]):
        self.msgs = msgs
```

The former makes `msgs` a class attribute, not an instance attribute, so it's shared between the class and all its instances, while the latter shares a single `list` with all instances that use the default for `msgs`. The solution to both is the same: Use a unique `list` for each:

```
class general:
    def __init__(self, msgs=()):
        self.msgs = list(msgs)  # Explicitly convert and shallow copy as list
```

A third possibility is that you did something silly like `msgs = []`, `gen0 = general(msgs)`, `gen1 = general(msgs)`, etc., or `gen0 = gen1 = gen2 = general([])`, or `listgens = [general()] * 3` or the like, all of which boil down to the same problem: You're storing a single reference to the same data multiple times, and you need to have different values.

Comment: thank you!! i see, i didn't make it an instance attribute! Been banging my head against the wall for an hour now. Thanks!!

Comment: @socrates: You're welcome. Always happy when my first psychic intuition works out. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger: can you also water divine?